# Is there a way to pass information from Google Chrome using an extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, web-scraping

I'm trying to hook up a C++ program to a Chrome extension.  Is there a way for a Chrome extension to communicate (i.e. pass data) to a separate process running on the same machine?

(Even something awkward such as writing to a file is better than nothing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **[chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-sendNativeMessage)** which can be used to send a message to a native application and **[chrome.runtime.connectNative](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-connectNative)** which allows for a more persistent connection.

You can find more info on Native Messaging in **[the docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging)**.

Answer (score 0):

For non-native apps ive done this a long time ago. Have your app register for a custom url handler as in myXapp:// . From your extension you could redirect to that link and this will cause your handler app to open and receive the "url" string. Hacky but should work.